# Cannot acces users Active Directory password information on production server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, ldap

I'm developing an MVC application and I have a routine that gets the currently logged on users password info and it works fine on my PC but when I publish my application to a live server on the domain, I don't seem to be able to gain access to the AD information. I have used very similar code in a currently running asp.net web application and it works just fine. I compared security settings on both applications and they look identical. Here is the routine:

```
 public int GetPasswordExpiration()
    {
        PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        string currUserName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        UserPrincipal currLogin = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, currUserName);
        DateTime passwordLastSet = currLogin.LastPasswordSet.Value; //here is where it chokes***
        int doyPasswordSet = passwordLastSet.DayOfYear;
        int doy = DateTime.Today.DayOfYear;
        int daysSinceLastset = (doy - doyPasswordSet);
        int daysTilDue = (120 - daysSinceLastset);
        return (daysTilDue);

    }
```

I am an administrator on the domain so I think I have an application permissions issue, but since the failing application has the same permissions as the working application, I'm not sure where to look next. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't this `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` apply to the identity of your IIS application pool if you are on the production server? Did you checked if the pool uses a domain account or a local application pool identity?

Comment: Both the application that returns the users password info and the problem application use the same pool.

Comment: You could use `UserPrincipal currLogin = UserPrincipal.Current` and be done with that...

Comment: Ok, I changed the code but now I'm getting this exception: ` Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'. Again, it works on my local machine, just not on the production server.

Comment: My personal experience with System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement indicates that it is not very robust and is prone to failure on simple tasks in unpredictable circumstances.  I'm not suggesting that this is a permanent solution, but have you tried using the less friendly by equally functional DirectoryEntry to query for this attribute instead?  If that doesn't work either then it would seem to imply a definite permission issue.

Comment: @Stephan I have not as of yet but may give it a shot. I am working with MS on this now and will post back if/when I get a solution.

Comment: @stephan Ok, I just tried using DirectoryEntry and I get the same results. I'm pretty convinced it is an IIS issue , just haven't found the cause yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answernig my own question because I want to post the code that works.  Wiktor Zychla nailed it when asking if WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name applied to the identity of the application pool rather than the logged in user. As a matter of fact it did, thanks Wiktor!

Here is the modified code that works. I did change the way I got the users identity (explained why below).

**Controller Code:**

```
using MyProject.Utilities;  // Folder where I created the CommonFunctions.cs Class

var cf = new CommonFunctions();
string user = User.Identity.Name;
ViewBag.PasswordExpires = cf.GetPasswordExpiration(user);
```

**Code in CommonFunctions**

```
public int GetPasswordExpiration(string user)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        UserPrincipal currLogin = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user);
        DateTime passwordLastSet = currLogin.LastPasswordSet.Value;
        int doyPasswordSet = passwordLastSet.DayOfYear;
        int doy = DateTime.Today.DayOfYear;
        int daysSinceLastset = (doy - doyPasswordSet);
        int daysTilDue = (120 - daysSinceLastset);
        return (daysTilDue);

    }
```

The one thing that clued me in was that I decided to just run all the code in my controller and when I did, I got a red squiggly saying "The name WindowsIdentity does not exist in this context":

string currUserName = *WindowsIdentity*.GetCurrent().Name;

Also, the reason I retrieved User.Identity.Name in the Controller and passed it to the function is because once I got things working and wanted to thin out my controller, I tried to get User.Identity.Name in the function but I got another red squiggly with the same message under User in this line:
 string user = User.Identity.Name;
So I figure this is a .net thing and just went with getting the User.Identiy.Name in the controller, pass it to the function and all is well. This one really tested my patience and I hope this post can help someone else.